# Array Bounds cannot appear in type specifier? VS

Tags: sql, vb.net

With regards to the subject line, I have already researched and cannot find the same kind of solution for my problem. Please see below my code where the error should come from :

```
Public Class Athletedb

Shared athlete As New Athlete


Public Shared Function GetAthletes(Dir As String) As List(Of Athlete)
    Dim athleteList As New List(Of Athlete)
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = AthleteManDB.GetConnection()

    Dim selectStatement As String =
        "SELECT Name, Surname, BirthDate, RegDate, Gender, Amount, MemberNumber" &
        "FROM Athletes" &
        "ORDER BY Surname"
    Dim selectCommand As OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection)


    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim textIn As OleDbDataReader = OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim athlete As Athlete
        Do While textIn.Read
            athlete = New Athlete
            athlete.Name = textIn("Name").ToString
            athlete.Surname = textIn("Surname").ToString
            athlete.Birthdate = textIn("Birthdate").ToString
            athlete.RegDate = textIn("RegDate").ToString
            athlete.Gender = textIn("Gender").ToString
            athlete.Amount = textIn("Amount").ToString
            athlete.MemberNumber = textIn("MemberNumber").ToString
            athleteList.Add(athlete)

        Loop
        textIn.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return athleteList

End Function

Public Shared Function SaveAthlete(Dir As String, athletes As List(Of Athlete))
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = AthleteManDB.GetConnection
    Dim insertStatement As String =
        "INSERT Athletes" &
        "(Name, Surname, Birthdate, RegDate, Gender, Amount, MemberNumber)" &
        "VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @Birthdate, @RegDate, @Gender, @Amount, @MemberNumber)"
    Dim insertCommand As New OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", athlete.Name)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", athlete.Name)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", athlete.Name)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDate", athlete.Name)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", athlete.Name)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", athlete.Name)
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberNumber", athlete.Name)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim selectStatement As String =
            "SELECT INDENT_CURRENT('Athletes') FROM Athletes"
        Dim selectCommand As New OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection)

    Catch ex As OleDbException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return athletes
End Function




Public Shared Function DeleteAthlete(Dir As String, athletes As List(Of Athlete)) As Boolean
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = AthleteManDB.GetConnection
    Dim deleteStatement As String =
        "DELETE FROM Athletes " &
        "WHERE Name = @Name " &
        "WHERE Surname = @Surname " &
        "WHERE Birthdate = @Birthdate " &
        "WHERE RegDate = @RegDate " &
        "WHERE Gender = @Gender " &
        "WHERE Amount = @Amount " &
        "WHERE MemberNumber = @MemberNumber "
    Dim deleteCommand As New OleDbCommand(deleteStatement, connection)
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", athlete.Name)
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", athlete.Name)
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", athlete.Name)
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDate", athlete.Name)
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", athlete.Name)
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", athlete.Name)
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberNumber", athlete.Name)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim count As Integer = deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
        If count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```

End Class

I am also getting a Reference to non shared member requires object reference on the below line and not sure what thats about

```
Dim textIn As OleDbDataReader = OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Sorry the error is in the line  
Dim selectCommand As OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection)

Comment: Try it like this:`Dim selectCommand As New OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection)`

Comment: Nevermind....I needed to add new to the line :S...

Comment: need help with the last below :

Comment: I am also getting a Reference to non shared member requires object reference on the below line and not sure what thats about Dim textIn As OleDbDataReader = OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()

Comment: You can't declare a variable and directly assign a value to it in one line. Try it like this:`Dim textIn As OleDbDataReader` `Set textIn = OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: Hey man thanks for the response, but still same problem

Comment: Could it be that you want to use selectCommand instead of OleDBCommmand? So `Set textIn = selectCommand.ExecuteReader() `

Comment: lollll well that worked. Thanks much man :)

Comment: Posting an answer so you can mark the question as answered

Comment: @gizlmo - This is VB.Net (according to the tag), you most certainly can declare a variable and assign it on a single line.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway uups, thought this was vba, didn't pay attention

Answer (score 0):

Since the OleDBCommand Class is Static, it doesn't allow to be used without creating an instance first. As you have already created an instance of it (selectCommand), you should use it:

```
textIn = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: `Set` is not valid in VB.Net.

Comment: alright, then provide a valid VB.Net solution please. never used it

Comment: Your answer is correct, it just doesn't need the `Set` keyword.

Comment: yeah you guys thanks got it to work....Gizlmo you helped also man thanks